# Ardupilot, atmega1280 and barometer

Tags: arduino, atmega, memory, atmel, eeprom

I'm working on a project and I need to know where the information taken by the barometer sensor are stored.
I think in the eeprom, but exactly where? Is there a specific address or register memory?

My goal is doing the ROP attack on the system.

I compiled the ArduPlane code (just the part of Ardupilot relative to the plane and not ground station), then found the .elf and I did the command

```
avr-objdump -S arduplane.elf > arduplane.lss
```

and now I have the istruction of all the arduplane.
In the section of the sensor I found the function

```
static int32_t read_barometer(void){
   barometer.read();
   return altitude_filter.apply(barometer.get_atitude()*100.0);
}
```

that in the lss became:

```
static void init_barometer(void)
{
    697e:   cf 93           push    r28
    6980:   df 93           push    r29
    barometer.calibrate(mavlink_delay);
    6982:   cc e8           ldi r28, 0x8C   ; 140
    6984:   dc e0           ldi r29, 0x0C   ; 12
    6986:   ce 01           movw    r24, r28
    6988:   6b e5           ldi r22, 0x5B   ; 91
    698a:   7e e4           ldi r23, 0x4E   ; 78
    698c:   0e 94 f6 8d     call    0x11bec ; 0x11bec <_ZN7AP_Baro9calibrateEPFvmE>
    }
    void            set_compass(Compass *compass) {
        _compass = compass;
    }
    void            set_barometer(AP_Baro *barometer) {
        _barometer = barometer;
    6990:   d0 93 8b 07     sts 0x078B, r29
    6994:   c0 93 8a 07     sts 0x078A, r28
    ahrs.set_barometer(&barometer);
    gcs_send_text_P(SEVERITY_LOW, PSTR("barometer calibration complete"));
    6998:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
    699a:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
    699c:   64 ec           ldi r22, 0xC4   ; 196
    699e:   7f e0           ldi r23, 0x0F   ; 15
    69a0:   0e 94 a4 34     call    0x6948  ; 0x6948 <_ZL15gcs_send_text_P12gcs_severityPK11prog_char_t>
}
    69a4:   df 91           pop r29
    69a6:   cf 91           pop r28
    69a8:   08 95           ret
```

Are r29 and r28 registers dedicated to the barometer?

Are 0x078B  and 0x78A the stack addresses for the information?

Comment: Please provide more information about your project. For example your circuit, the barometer sensor part number, code, ...

Comment: The lss seems to be for a different function or incomplete. Further, why not just use a call to barometer.get_altitude() instead of mucking around in the stack? It doesn't seem like its worth the effort. Finally, I'd look closer at altitude_filter.apply() if I were looking for a place where I could tap to get the instantaneous value of the altitude as tracked by the system.

Comment: @ChintalagiriShashank Than you for your answer, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: For starters, the lss is for barometer_init. 

And what i mean is that an ROP attack is silly when you have the sources and are compiling it yourself what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to do an ROP attack changing the barometer value of the arduplane.

Comment: Start with providing the correct lss for the function. Also, the lss for attitude_filter.update would be useful. Depending on what that function does, you will likely need to dig deeper and find the point where the value is actually stored in a variable. And no, r28 and r29 are not reserved for the barometer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption**: *The question refers to the now discontinued ArduPilot Mega APM-1, which uses the atmega1280 microcontroller.*

The information from the barometric sensor is not explicitly stored anywhere in the code AFAIK, unless you are logging location parameters, in which case your code defines where it will be stored.

Instantaneous barometric absolute value is obtained by `barometer.read()`. This returns absolute pressure sensed by the barometer, which may be of limited value, since temperature and calibration values need to be taken into account.

Altitude transform of barometric reading is obtained by `read_barometer()` which returns an `int32_t` in centimeters. This value further depends on the baseline calibrated from `barometer.read()` at reboot or start-up, and incorporates temperature related computation.

It is simple to add code to log the barometer value to a volatile variable or array, using the Arduino IDE.

---

Speculating that the barometer value requirement stems from some random barometric reading glitches observed in use, this is a known issue in older releases, and still apparently remains in release 2.5, but is much reduced, or has been solved: User reports differ on this.

Recommendations if this is the problem:

- Upgrade to the 2.5 release of the software
- After start-up, wait about 5 minutes for the electronics to stabilize in temperature, then press reset to reboot and re-calibrate all sensors.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helped me a little.
My project is about the ROP attack on this system. So I need the exact point on the stack  where the information are.

Comment: @DarkCoffee Since the datum is retrieved cyclically, on-demand, I don't see that a specific fixed stack position would exist. However, you do have the requisite method calls now, so if you want to probe the stack for those, you might get somewhere.

Comment: I edit my question with more detail. Please let me know what you think about it.